# C++: fread() causing assertion error?

Tags: c++

I have an error cause by `fread()` and it says:

```
File: f:\ dd\vctools\ crt_bld\ self_x86\ crt\ src\fread.c
Line: 102
Expression: (stream != NULL)
For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

What should I do? I have already include `<stdio.h>` in my program. I'm currently developing my project using Visual C++ MFC.

Comment: Bertrand is somewhat right, though not helping :) As you don't supply any of the context, we can confirm what the assert sais. [Assert ain't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: Your fopen() call failed and you forgot to check for that.

Answer (score 6):

`Expression: (stream != NULL)` explains it all.

You're passing a `NULL` stream to [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) and you should not.

Comment: Yes. Check your code, and see where you call "fread(...)". Have a look at this reference, especially the example: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/, try to find out the difference between this code and your code. The "pFile" in the example, is where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that you have a proper FILE object to send to fread? Try to check if it is null before using it. Also check out that documentation on assert, it's not about what files you have #included or not. This is a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fread()` takes as the an argument a `FILE*`:

```
size_t __cdecl fread(
    void *buffer,
    size_t elementSize,
    size_t count,
    FILE *stream
)
```

The `FILE*` you are sending it is NULL. you should debug your program and find out why that is so.

You could have found this information on your on, the same way I did, by opening the file `f:\ dd\vctools\ crt_bld\ self_x86\ crt\ src\fread.c` in your computer and looking what it does on line 102.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `(Press Retry to debug the application)` part of the message.

If you enter the debugger, you will likely end up at the assert() and can check the call stack to find where the call to fread comes from. Then figure out why the FILE* is null there! Perhaps a failed call to fopen?